# Ways to save data without NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

What other ways than `NSUserDefaults` are there to save and get back Custom Objects? For me, `NSUserDefaults` has become too much of a hassle (it's not saving correctly), so I'm looking for another way to save data that will work. (I've already posted my problems, and I really just want to look for other ways to save data)

EDIT: I also need to be able to save things like UIIMages and UIButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can save data as normal `text` file or `plist` file.
2. You can use `SQLLite` to save data.

Other than this if you are using server driven application, then you can save your data on server and get back when you need that.

Comment: @ManOx - images you can store in application bundle.

Answer (score 1):

UIImages should be saved by creating a PNG or JPEG representation, then writing that NSData block out as you see fit. See [UIImagePNGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation).

UIButtons should be serialized/deserialized using the [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. Archives can take care of this for you.

NSData and UIButtons both support NSCoding, so I would recommend archiving instead of NSUserDefaults. See NSCoding for the beginning of that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

You cans use plist or coreData.As you used NSUserDefaults , that means data is quite small so plist will be a good idea.Both are apple's so quite effiecient .If data gets really large you can use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

To store custom objects, you need to make sure your custom objects implemented NSCoding protocol.  Here is Apple's doc on [NSCoding.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)  . If you need a tutorial on how to implement NSCoding protocol, check out [this site.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager)    To save UIImage to a file, you can convert the image to    [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then using NSData's writeToFile method to write to a file.  There are numerous examples on how to do the last part on SO.  Here is [one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios)