# Show recorded audios in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

I have a view responsible for recording audio. How can i record several audios and show them in a table view?
I'm trying to use docs directory to save the recorded audios:

```
NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *recordedAudio = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:newAudio];
```

newAudio is a string that contains new audio name typed by the user with the suffix .m4a.
To retrieve the saved audios i'm trying something like this:

```
NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *folderContents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentsFolder];
```

I expected folderContents would have all the audios stored at documentsFolder so a could load my table, but its count is 0. I'm new in docs directory, probably i'm missing something, or doing all wrong.

What is wrong, or there is another way to accomplish that?

Comment: This will return you the string or path not the array..

Comment: More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the contents of the documents directory incorrectly. This is the right way:

`NSArray *folderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsFolder error:nil];`

Documents is not a file, it is a folder.

**edit:** This is how you save a file

Assuming you have an NSData object such as

`NSData *audioData = ...; // initialiazed with your recording`

After you create your `recordedAudio` string, which is actually just the filename you want to write to (should probably called `audioPath` or something), you need to add this:

`[audioData writeToFile:recordedAudio atomically:YES];`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this later and come back in here to tell if worked. And the way i'm saving is correct?

Comment: You're actually not saving the file either. Editing my answer to show you how.