# How can I store an image programmatically in my apps folder at iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save An Image To Application Documents Folder From UIView On IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios)

I want to store image in my apps folder programmatically  which I taken by UIImagePiker (camera or photogallery). I am a beginner in iOS programming.

Comment: PLEASE use the search function before posting questions. This question has been asked many, Many, MANY times before.

Comment: don't worry its a good question, new people make such mistakes but its ok it can be ignored initially.

Comment: yes you are right. but they should spend their searching efforts before ask any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving an image:

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/aName.png"];

   [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```