# how to save captured photos within an app iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an iphone application in which

1) i want to take the picture in an application that i know how to do
2) now i want to save that picture in specified folder of an application only. Is it possible to do so. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did You gone through it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

You can use the following code in **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** delegate implementation

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

//obtaining saving path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

//extracting image from the picker and saving it
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];   
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
}
```