# iOS: image rotates after retrieve from Application folder

Tags: ios, image

After I tried the codes in [Save An Image To Application Documents Folder From UIView On IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios)
I found it works on iPhone.
But when I retrieve the png image from folder and show it on imageView, the photo rotate 90 degrees anticlockwise.
So, how to solve it ?  Thank you guys for help sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same problem and i have solved it using class files please download class files from below link and drag & drop in to your project

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/52soto4mxpdcqhz/iFrkKttSv0

after that import it in the view controller where you are retrieving image

```
#import "UIImage+fixOrientation.h"
```

and before you save image to application folder put below code

```
UIImage *image = [selectedImage fixOrientation];
```

Comment: It works. But I have to call fixOrientation before I save the photo to folder, not before retrieving from folder and putting to imageView. Can I use UIImage+fixOrientation.h for commercial use ?

Comment: I found the same thing on pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/FRHfjXaf ).h and ( http://pastebin.com/525DYJfE ).m, incase the dropbox link disappears.