# Saving Photo to a directory

Tags: ios, save, photo

How do you try to save a photo to a directory that I made

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;


    NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tops",@"bottom",@"right",@"left",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryNames[i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
    }
}
```

I am making the user to take a picture inside the app and want the user to choose which directory he wants to save into.  How should I do this?

Comment: You should use to asset library. You should read more information it doesn't do in a hurry. You ought to understand asset library work algorithm

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios