# saving photo automatically that is displayed in a UIIMage to a directory

Tags: ios, uiimage, directory, save, photo

I want to save photo in directory.  However I made directories using this code in the view controller.

```
  NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
```

The UIImage is displaying what the user has taken.  I would want to save the photo automatically to one of my directories that I made(for example hats) when it is displayed on the UIIMage.Below is my code for displaying to UIImage after photo is taken.  Is there away to automatically save to one of the directories??

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image { //process captured image, crop, resize and rotate
    haveImage = YES;

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //Device is ipad
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1022));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1022)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 130, 768, 768);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
        //or use the UIImage wherever you like

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    }else{ //Device is iphone
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 426));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 426)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 320);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }

    //adjust image orientation based on device orientation
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"landscape left image");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"landscape right");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"upside down");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"upside upright");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}







- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)switchCamera:(id)sender { //switch cameras front and rear cameras
    if (cameraSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        FrontCamera = YES;
        [self initializeCamera];
    }
    else {
        FrontCamera = NO;
        [self initializeCamera];
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, 'automatically'?

Comment: I am making the user take a picture and is displayed in the UIImage. I want the picture that is displayed in UIImage saved into "one" of my directories that I made.  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: /Do you want a directory picked automatically?

Comment: Yes as I have in the code I have made directories. I just want to save the photo  to directory "right"

Comment: So by what rule are you supposed to pick a directory?

Comment: I don't get your pick directory. I just want to save the pictures into the directory that I made called left. Look at my first code .  I don't want to make the user choose which directory they want to save to.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What problem are you having, specifically, with saving the photo?

Comment: OK I will simplify the question.  I do not know how to save into a directory that "I" have made(LOOK AT THE TOP I HAVE MADE DIRECTORIES named hats bottom right and left.  I just simply want to save the photo that is **displaying** in the UIImage AUTOMATICALLY (saying that user does not have to do anything like pushing save button) to the directory called left.  The UIImage is showing the picture that the **user** has taken. I cannot simplify my question more.. Which part do you not understand???

Comment: So, like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios

Comment: Yes But I want to save it to a specific directory that I have made. which I can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put this at the bottom of `processImage:`

```
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryNames[2]]; // "right" is at index 2, per comments & code
NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; // you maybe want to incorporate a timestamp into the name to avoid duplicates
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: How do you set the directory name that I have made?

Comment: `folderPath` is the directory you made, you see that, right? `filePath` just appends a file name to it. Is that clear?

Comment: What do you mean 'what happened' to it?

Comment: You made a directory, and this code writes data to a file in that directory, so that's what happened to it, it got a file written to it.

Comment: And also what is right is at index 2? I am also getting an error in directoryNames on first code.