# How to find NSDocumentDirectory in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to get path to Documents folder with code:

```
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory:0,NSSearchPathDomainMask:0,true)
```

but Xcode gives error: `Cannot convert expression's type 'AnyObject[]!' to type 'NSSearchPathDirectory'`

I'm trying to understand what is wrong in the code.

Comment: There were several edits to this question which were adding possible solutions. The whole thing was a mess. I've rolled back to the first version for clarity. Answers don't belong in a question and should be posted as answers. I'm available to discuss if someone thinks my rollback is too radical. Thanks.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Apparently, the compiler thinks `NSSearchPathDirectory:0` is an array, and of course it expects the type `NSSearchPathDirectory` instead. Certainly not a helpful error message.

But as to the reasons:

First, you are confusing the argument names and types. Take a look at the function definition:

```
func NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    directory: NSSearchPathDirectory,
    domainMask: NSSearchPathDomainMask,
    expandTilde: Bool) -> AnyObject[]!
```

- `directory` and `domainMask` are the names, you are using the types, but you should leave them out for functions anyway. They are used primarily in methods.
- Also, Swift is strongly typed, so you shouldn't just use 0. Use the enum's value instead.
- And finally, it returns an array, not just a single path.

So that leaves us with (updated for Swift 2.0):

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

and for Swift 3:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
```

Comment: This answer failed in Xcode 6.0. The cast must be to `NSString` rather than `String`.

Comment: @DanielT. Just tried again and `String` works in Xcode 6.0 and 6.1. Generally, `String` and `NSString` are bridged automatically in Swift. Maybe you had to cast to `NSString` for another reason.

Comment: Did you try it in a playground or in an actual app? The results are different. The code casts to a `String` in a playground, but not in an app. Check out question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450003/swift-get-documents-directory-returns-empty-string/26452472#26452472)

Comment: Both, actually. Could be a subtle bug in Swift, I suppose ... I'll just edit the answer to be safe. :) Thanks

Comment: running again the app generates a different path, why?: (1) `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9E18A573-6429-434D-9B42-08642B643970/Documents` (2) `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/77C8EA95-B77A-474D-8522-1F24F854A291/Documents`

Comment: For Swift NuB's (like me), the first two arguments of the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains function are of type `enum NSSearchPathDirectory` and `struct NSSearchPathDomainMask` respectively. Hence Swift allows you to drop the enum/struct name before the dot. That is why `NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask` is equivalent to `.UserDomainMask` within the context of this function call.

Comment: @János did you every find out why ?? I have just started seeing this same problem, every time I run the app in the debugger it changes the path name !?  Weird - but I guess just never save the full path, always recreate the path to the file each time the app starts up !?

Comment: This is not an issue, this is security reasons. iOS changes App container each launch.

Answer (score 48):

**Swift 3.0 and 4.0**

Directly getting first element from an array will potentially cause exception if the path is not found. So calling `first` and then unwrap is the better solution

```
if let documentsPathString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
    //This gives you the string formed path
}

if let documentsPathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    //This gives you the URL of the path
}
```

Answer (score 33):

The modern recommendation is to use NSURLs for files and directories instead of NSString based paths:

[image]

So to get the Document directory for the app as an NSURL:

```
func databaseURL() -> NSURL? {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

    if let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as? NSURL {
        // This is where the database should be in the documents directory
        let finalDatabaseURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("items.db")

        if finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
            // The file already exists, so just return the URL
            return finalDatabaseURL
        } else {
            // Copy the initial file from the application bundle to the documents directory
            if let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("items", withExtension: "db") {
                let success = fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: finalDatabaseURL, error: nil)
                if success {
                    return finalDatabaseURL
                } else {
                    println("Couldn't copy file to final location!")
                }
            } else {
                println("Couldn't find initial database in the bundle!")
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Couldn't get documents directory!")
    }

    return nil
}
```

This has rudimentary error handling, as that sort of depends on what your application will do in such cases. But this uses file URLs and a more modern api to return the database URL, copying the initial version out of the bundle if it does not already exist, or a nil in case of error.

Answer (score 24):

**Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
let documentDirectoryURL =  try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

**Xcode 7.1.1 • Swift 2.1**

```
let documentDirectoryURL =  try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
```

Answer (score 23):

Usually I prefer to use this extension:

**Swift 3.x and Swift 4.0**:

```
extension FileManager {
    class func documentsDir() -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    class func cachesDir() -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
        return paths[0]
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.x**:

```
extension NSFileManager {
    class func documentsDir() -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    class func cachesDir() -> String {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
        return paths[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: where to call this?

Comment: To every part of your code you need: `let path = FileManager.documentsDir()+("/"+"\(fileName)")` , you can call it without differences between thread (main or background).

Answer (score 14):

For everyone who looks example that works with Swift 2.2, Abizern code with modern do try catch handle of error

```
func databaseURL() -> NSURL? {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

    if let documentDirectory:NSURL = urls.first { // No use of as? NSURL because let urls returns array of NSURL
        // This is where the database should be in the documents directory
        let finalDatabaseURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("OurFile.plist")

        if finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
            // The file already exists, so just return the URL
            return finalDatabaseURL
        } else {
            // Copy the initial file from the application bundle to the documents directory
            if let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("OurFile", withExtension: "plist") {

                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: finalDatabaseURL)
                } catch let error as NSError  {// Handle the error
                    print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.localisedDescription)")
                }

            } else {
                print("Couldn't find initial database in the bundle!")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Couldn't get documents directory!")
    }

    return nil
}
```

**Update**
I've missed that new swift 2.0 have guard(Ruby unless analog), so with guard it is much shorter and more readable

```
func databaseURL() -> NSURL? {

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

// If array of path is empty the document folder not found
guard urls.count != 0 else {
    return nil
}

let finalDatabaseURL = urls.first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("OurFile.plist")
// Check if file reachable, and if reacheble just return path
guard finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) else {
    // Check if file is exists in bundle folder
    if let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("OurFile", withExtension: "plist") {
        // if exist we will copy it
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: finalDatabaseURL)
        } catch let error as NSError { // Handle the error
            print("File copy failed! Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Our file not exist in bundle folder")
        return nil
    }
    return finalDatabaseURL
}
return finalDatabaseURL 
}
```

Answer (score 14):

More convenient **Swift 3** method:

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                             in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Comment: Or even `FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to instantiate a new file manager every time we want to get an URL for Documents directory.

Comment: I thought it's the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 8b4 Swift 3.0**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually i prefer like below in **swift 3**, because i can add file name and create a file easily

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    let databasePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("db.sqlite3").path
    print("directory path:", documentsURL.path)
    print("database path:", databasePath)
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: databasePath) {
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: databasePath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `absoluteString` is wrong. to get the file path fro a fileURL you need to get its `.path` property

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this line in App delegate like this and it will print path like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)
        return true
    }
```

Copy the path and paste it in go To Folder in finder by right clicking on it then enter
[image]

Open the file in Xcode

[image]