# Swift get Documents Directory returns empty String

Tags: swift

According to [How to find NSDocumentDirectory in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055146/how-to-find-nsdocumentdirectory-in-swift)  I wrote the next code:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let files = NSFileManager().enumeratorAtPath(documentsPath)
var myString:String = "/"
while let file: AnyObject = files?.nextObject() {
    myString += (file as String + "/")
}
println(myString)
```

But, actually the problem is that, when I debug the program, documentsPath equals to (String) "", after executing `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` command. Besides, I'm trying to do this not in MainViewController, I'm trying to execute this command in TableViewController.

[image]

However, it works in playground;
It doesn't work for any project that I create

```
let docdir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String + "Test.txt"
```

returns the correct path, wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the documentation for `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and it says,

> You should consider using the NSFileManager methods
>   URLsForDirectory:inDomains: and
>   URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:. which return
>   URLs, which are the preferred format.

And the following works perfectly:

```
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    println(urls[0])
```

That said, your code is failing because the items in the array returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains are not Strings. If you want to keep your original code, just change `as String` to `as NSString`

Comment: This could be a bug in Apple's SDK. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is returning an array of `NSPathStore2` objects, which can be cast into `NSStrings`, but not `Strings`.