# How to modify plist in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, plist

I want to be able to modify values from my plist in swift but I'm having trouble figuring it out. So far I can read the values in my array but that's it.

```
var playersDictionaryPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayersInfo", ofType: "plist")

var playersDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: playersDictionaryPath!)

var playersNamesArray = playersDictionary?.objectForKey("playersNames")? as NSArray

[println(playersNamesArray)][1]
```

Comment: if the `plist` is part of the bundle, you can't; but if you copy it into the `Documents` folder and you can update it there.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you can't write to a plist file inside your app resources. So you will need to save your edited plist to another directory. Like your `NSDocumentDirectory`.

[As in this answer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055146/how-to-find-nsdocumentdirectory-in-swift) you can get the document-path like that:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
```

But to answer your question, you can edit an `NSMutableDictionary` like that:

```
//add entries:
playersDictionary.setValue("yourValue", forKey: "yourKey")

//edit entries:
playersDictionary["yourKey"] = "newValue" //Now has value 'newValue'

//remove entries:
playersDictionary.removeObjectForKey("yourKey")
```

If you want to edit your `NSArray` on the other hand, you should use an `NSMutableArray` instead.

Comment: We can't write to custom plist in our bundle?

Answer (score 3):

I found how to do it:

```
    var playersDictionaryPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayersInfo", ofType: "plist")

    var playersDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: playersDictionaryPath!)

    var playersNamesArray = playersDictionary?.objectForKey("playersNames")? as NSMutableArray

    //this is a label I have called player1Name
    playersNamesArray[0] = "\(player1Name.text)"

    playersDictionary?.writeToFile(playersDictionaryPath!, atomically: true)
```

btw, thanks for the NSMutableArray, I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: can you edit the background capabilities in the info.plist file?