# Cannot find my downloaded file in the document folder via fileExistsAtPath

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm facing an issue when trying to read my downloaded audio file from the document folder. The file '032000.mp3' really exists on the download folder(see illustration)

```
  F501141C-4D7B-42D9-83DE-83DE0C04AA66
  |- Documents
  |-- audios
  |--- 0
  |---- 032
  |------ 032000.mp3


  var path: String = "/Users/abm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/52FDA0EC-1A3F-4A69-9359-96511E21E172/data/Containers/Data/Application/F501141C-4D7B-42D9-83DE-83DE0C04AA66/Documents/audios/0/032/032000.mp3"
  println("fileExistsAtPath= \(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path))") // --> false
```

Note: Opening the downloaded file via terminal just works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get path for documents folder dynamically. Every times, when you start application in simulator, application folder name changed. See this answer [How to find NSDocumentDirectory in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055146/how-to-find-nsdocumentdirectory-in-swift)

Comment: Thanx for you replay:
I already did, the path above is automatically generated