# Seems like my Text file isn't storing persistently in Documents Directory

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdocumentdirectory

### NOTE: Possibly Resolved: Was missing ".path!" to documentsUrl.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)

I am saving a text file to Applications Documents Directory. Using

```
var path = ""
let date = NSDate()
let file = "\(date).txt"
let joined = "\n".join(ActionArray)
if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
    let dir = dirs[0]
    path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    println(path)

    joined.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);
}
```

println `path`

> /Users/dustin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EA056FC-114D-4C98-9B35-29B46760BE3A/data/Containers/Data/Application/2AB9FD4A-25AB-4385-9CFB-A66AEFA8C1A3/Documents/2015-05-16 08:24:08 +0000.txt

Then store `path` and some other data to an `Entity`, which will be used to call back the text file later.

When I do a fetchRequest on the entity and print out the array I get

> (
>       " (entity: Entity; id: 0xd000000000040000  ; data: {\n    date = \"2015-05-16 08:18:20 +0000\";\n    path = \"/Users/dustin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EA056FC-114D-4C98-9B35-29B46760BE3A/data/Containers/Data/Application/4A9C17AB-57C1-47CB-B9B1-E0E5CA494B4E/Documents/2015-05-16 08:24:08\";\n})"
>   )

the `path` is now missing the " +0000". When I call on the path from the `Entity.path`, my text file is found...BUT when I completely close app (home-swipe-^), the text file search...

```
let fileContent = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
var fileContentArr = split(fileContent) {$0 == "\n"}
```

I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

---

What am I doing wrong to write a persistent text file to draw upon later regardless if App reset?

---

EDIT: I've taken advice to notice directory path changes between App sessions, So I've instead stored file name to `Entity` and get Documents Path at read time. I still get error.

I'm doing some debugging and my println's are as follows

```
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as! NSURL

    // now lets get the directory contents (including folders)
    if let directoryContents =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsUrl.path!, error: nil) {
        println(directoryContents)
        println(documentsUrl.path!)
    }
```

> [2015-05-17 04:25:48 +0000.txt, 2015-05-17 04:31:07 +0000.txt, iPro_Poker_HH_swift.sqlite, iPro_Poker_HH_swift.sqlite-shm, iPro_Poker_HH_swift.sqlite-wal]
>
> /Users/dustindobrilovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EA056FC-114D-4C98-9B35-29B46760BE3A/data/Containers/Data/Application/7CD25462-947C-40AA-97DB-4A845FED1451/Documents

My Entity Fetch array println()

> (
>   " (entity: Hand; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: {\n    path = \"2015-05-17 04:31:07 +0000.txt\";\n})"
>   )

I then combine `documentsUrl.path!` with `path` from entity to get println(stringDocumentsURL)

> file:/Users/dustindobrilovic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EA056FC-114D-4C98-9B35-29B46760BE3A/data/Containers/Data/Application/7CD25462-947C-40AA-97DB-4A845FED1451/Documents/2015-05-17 04:31:07 +0000.txt

This is where Im getting a warning which is very next line.

```
let fileContent = String(contentsOfFile: stringDocumentsURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find my downloaded file in the document folder via fileExistsAtPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274360/cannot-find-my-downloaded-file-in-the-document-folder-via-fileexistsatpath)

Comment: ok but even on a real device.. it crashes

Comment: You probably don't want the AllDomainsMask but rather the UserDomainMask

Comment: Closing the app might clear the Entity from memory so you'll have to rebuild the path information.

Comment: no entity remains even when closing app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path changes across launches. Try to persist only the relative part of the path and reconstruct the absolute path before accessing it.

Comment: so in my case I need to store `Documents/2015-05-16 08:24:08 +0000.txt`, Since Im using date as name of text file...then append this stored  suffix and add it to path at read time?

Comment: when speaking of launch, we are talking about starting and stopping the App correct...not each time we build from Xcode?

Comment: my Edited section took your advice, now the full paths match, but still finding a nil even though the file shows in folder.

Comment: If you have verified the file exists at the path, it might be the encoding or something else that's wrong with the content of the file. Can you check the error (instead of providing a nil pointer)? Or can you remove '!' at the end of the line or change it to '?'