# Swift 2.1 NSFileManager copyItemAtPath failing with Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, swift2

After upgrading my project to Swift 2.1, `NSFileManger` `copyItemAtPath` is throwing the following error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file "Settings.plist" couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
NSFilePath=/Users/nick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95856F10-9770-44B5-B990-B461E6991B79/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/17AAAD05-33FE-470A-9617-C8E378371E2E/MyApp.app/Settings.plist,
NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/nick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95856F10-9770-44B5-B990-B461E6991B79/data/Containers/Data/Application/020503D6-F7CE-47D2-83A7-D4B7D86E6D1D/Documents/Settings.plist, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x7994daf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Both the underlying source file and destination folder exist, but the copy always fails.

```
let _documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let storePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: _documentsDirectory).URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(storeName).plist").absoluteString

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(storePath)) {
    if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(storeName, ofType:"plist") {
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: storePath)
                return storePath
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
                return nil
            }
        }...
```

The file exists and `print("Exists:", fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(bundle))` returns true.

After reviewing 
[How to find NSDocumentDirectory in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055146/how-to-find-nsdocumentdirectory-in-swift) and others, I have tried a number of different methods to obtain the Documents directory and the main bundle resources, but I just can't get the file to copy.

Everything was working perfectly in Swift 1.2.

Comment: Oops - apologies, was copying code that I was trying to test if the filename was the issue.  Have amended.

Comment: Then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135305/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-fileexistsatpath-returns-false-instead-of-true: `absoluteString` is the wrong method to convert a URL to the file path `storePath`.

Comment: Thanks, changing `.absoluteString` to `.path!` did the trick.