# FileManager says file doesn't exist when it does

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, uigraphicscontext

I have a use case that requires a `UIImage` to be saved to the documents directory - then the `UIImage` needs to be converted into a PDF and saved to the documents directory.

**CODE TO CONVERT TO PDF**

```
var filePath = NSString(string: self.selectedMedia!.imagePath!)

if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath as String) {

       filePath = filePath.deletingPathExtension as NSString
       filePath = NSString(string: filePath.appendingPathExtension("PDF")!)

       if let image = UIImage(data: self.selectedMedia?.image! as! Data) {

           let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

           UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath as String, rect, nil);
           UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(rect, nil);
           UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
           image.draw(in: rect)
           UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

           self.selectedMedia?.imagePath = filePath as String

           CoreData.save()
       }

       self.showPDFEditor()
   }
else {
   print("Missing File At Path \(filePath)")
}
```

**ISSUE**

*`FileManager` says that a file does not exist when it does.* The first time this is executed, **before** we create the PDF, FileManager can detect that image PDF does indeed exist. But **After** we create the PDF from the image - even though the image PNG is still in the documents directory untouched (see image below of app container for proof), `FileManager` says the PNG does not exist?

[image]

**QUESTION**

Why does `FileManager` ignore the obvious truth and keep my application from functioning?

Comment: Print the path and compare it with the expected one.

Comment: I did. They are identical.

Comment: I met the exactly same problem! Looking for answers!

Comment: @HanXu I answered my own question. See if this helps you out.

Comment: @BrandonA, great! It works! THX!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Never store the complete file path**

My PDF and Images were residing under the `Documents` directory within the iOS file system. iOS will change the `root path` to the documents directory every time that you run the application. So saving an `imagePath` as I was above would work just fine, *until I restarted the app*. That is because I was storing the *entire* path to my `selectedMedia` object.

### This now - `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A31EDFD-8644-45A5-8381-FE189E27D6E5/Documents/`

### May be this later - `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/URID09RE-5711-TI70-1252-OP4G5JH3WDST/Documents/`

See how the `Application/someLongNumber/` is different. This is why when you check if a file is in your documents directory and in fact is there, but the root **path** has changed.

---

### **What should you do?**

Instead of storing the entire file path just store the subpath *from* the documents directory. So what I did was created a subfolder within the documents directory called `Media` that I save the file to and the path I store to my `imagePath` on my objects would be `Media/theFileName.PNG`.

So what you need to do is generate the path to the `/Documents` directory **at run time**. I can not stress this part enough. This will guarantee you are accessing the actual documents directory **each time**. Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055475/3911918) for tips on how to generate the path to documents directory.

After you have the path to the run time documents directory just add your stored path to the end of that and it should look something like this:

### `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/URID09RE-5711-TI70-1252-OP4G5JH3WDST/Documents/Media/theFileName.PNG`

Comment: let FManager = FileManager.default
        if let documentsPathURL = FManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            print(documentsPathURL.absoluteString)
            do
            {
                let flist = try FManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsPathURL.absoluteString)
                print(flist)
                
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                
            }

        }
        didn't work

Comment: file:///Users/martian2049/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1C4BEC1-02B8-4C54-81CD-A777E4A68B5A/data/Containers/Data/Application/AE887138-B40E-4325-9A3C-DBAFED35475B/Documents/
The folder “Documents” doesn’t exist.