# What is the id in URL path?

Tags: ios

Recently I realize that in URL path to local file one path element changed: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A6ED77D7-3A57-47BC-BD41-B1F857529D0F` I mean `A6ED77D7-3A57-47BC-BD41-B1F857529D0F` sometimes it stay the same and sometimes it is different than before.

I found this when after I save the whole path in db I wasn't able to read a file again because FileManager said that file doesn't exist.

I'd like to ask what this id is, when it changes?

Comment: can u add the code where it saves the file and when it is store in your database.

Comment: It's an ID for your app data container. When you save a path in your data base never save the full path, but just the last part and use for example `NSDocumentDirectory` to get the path to the document directory.

Comment: Don't save the whole path, save what's after. It's a identifier, should be some hash/UUID with build name, date, version, etc.? That's why it may change after rebuild/install/

Comment: @rckoenes when it changes? after every installation or after every start up?

Comment: After installation and update as far as I can tell. But you should really read the answers of the linked question. This contains a link to [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10) which explains all you need to know about the iOS filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a path to the documents directory which will be changed everytime you run the application. Following would be helpful for you:  [FileManager says file doesn't exist when it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138827/filemanager-says-file-doesnt-exist-when-it-does)