# How to share Image in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimage

I tried to share a image that I generate by my own. However when I tried to share the image it doesn't works well. 
here is the code to share

```
     func shareQR(){
        //mainImage is the view that hold the image I want to share
        let tempImage = view.mainImage.image

        let imageToShare = [ tempImage ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare as! [UIImage], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop ]

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So I tried to debug and the result is my tempImage value is the same with the one I want to share. And then I tried to hardcode the image and become `let tempImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")`
and tap share button, and it works perfectly.

So I figured out, did I have to save my image to local file first and then called it ?

If yes how ? I tried use this code but failed.

```
 // Create path.
 let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let filePath = "\(paths[0])/temp.png"

 // Save image.
 UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)?.write(to: filePath)
```

> the error is : cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected
>   argument type 'URL' in this line 
>   `UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage!)?.write(to: filePath)`

Or maybe I dont need to save image? how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your variable `image` is a `String` variable instead of a `UIImage` (hence the error that you have posted). To confirm this theory, add the following line in your code

```
print(tempImage)
```

after

```
let tempImage = view.mainImageimage
```

If it prints the image name, then your variable is a `String` variable. If it prints something along the lines of `UIImage`, then it's an actual image and we can further investigate the issue. Let me know what you get in result

**Edit:**
To store a file locally, use the following code

```
if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage) {
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
    try? data.write(to: filename)
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: this is the result `Optional(<UIImage: 0x177934c0>, {153, 153})`

Comment: so it seems that the `tempImage` is in fact storing a `UIImage`. My next question would be that what is the difference between `view.mainImage.image` and `mainView.barcodeImage.image`. Since you are not using the `tempImage` in the code snippet that you have shared, you might want to replace `mainView.barcodeImage.image` with `tempImage`. Alternatively, you can try to print out the value of `imageToShare` to make sure that it is in fact a `UIImage` as well

Comment: ah yes sorry let me fix my code a little bit. That's a wrong one I tried to manipulate before but failed.

Comment: One thing I can say for sure is that the `image` variable in `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)?.write(to: filePath)` is a `String` variable judging by the error.

Comment: the code is fixed. just a minor typo there. Did I have to save my image to local first to share image ? or I don't need to do that ? Because I've tried to share image using local & without using local image. Using local image can be shared but without can't

Comment: You need to use a URL. Just get the documentDirectory URL and append pathComponent  (fileName) to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812674/2303865

Comment: As per my understanding, the line `let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare as! [UIImage], applicationActivities: nil)` expects an array of `fileURL`s instead of an array of `UIImages`. You might have to store the images locally and then use the `fileURL`s of said images

Comment: then how should i write in code ? i'm a little bit confused here

Comment: Note that saving the image as PNG will discard its orientation info

Comment: I use the code you given, now the Share activity is become nothing. Before there's option to shared, save image and etc. now All disappear

Comment: and I tried to debug the code you give to me after this part it just skip over so the code doesn't go inside. `if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage)`

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145335/how-to-share-image-in-swift