# How to save and retrieve an image in iOS(for profile picture)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, save, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app,I have to add profile picture from

***1.Camera***

or

***2.Photo library.***

***This part is done***.Now I want to save the image locally and retrieve the image whenever the profile view is loaded.How can I do this?

I went through the accepted answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios).But I had doubts regarding the image name and all.Kindly let me know the correct method for doing this.Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the issue with that accepted answer, sorry?

Comment: ok,let me know the best practice for doing this,if you don't mind.Saving it to the database as NSData or creating a path and saving it to the photo library.Which is the best practice?

Comment: i'm super confused, sorry. i am under the impression you wish to save it locally, and then load it locally. where has the database part came from? you can just save it to a path and then load it from a path :D

Comment: the accepted answer looks fine.