# Can i Save an image on let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() on swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

i want to take a picture an save it on NSUserDefaults an then show taht image on other view its that posible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you shouldn't do it. Save to the file system, not to the user defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but you shouldn't do it. Save an image to the file system, not to the user defaults. It is data, not a preference. And it is relatively huge.

Comment: thats a good point, dou yo have any links or tutoral on saving an image to the file system im new on ios developer

Comment: What have you tried/googled/researched? Twenty seconds on google got me this, which I think is all you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios